# How to get the current appID from url?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-app-requests

I have an app in facebook, and I want to use this very same system on a different app as well. I have all data stored in a database (appid, appsecret, pageid etc), but if I load the app in facebook, I can't figure out what appid the current app is.

For example:
When I visit app_1234567890123456, my app has to figure out like "hey, this is app with ID 1234567890123456, let's see if I have that one in my database"

But now my app is more like "wtf? I really have no clue what all of this is".

I know facebook has this thing $facebook->getAppId, but in order to do that, I need to connect with facebook with an app secret and an appid, and those are 2 things I don't know at that moment.
I can only make the connection with facebook if I know the appID from the current url.

Comment: Both apps are served from the same exact url?

Comment: They both have different appid's, but they both go to http://example.com/facebookapp

Answer (score 1):

When a user goes to your canvas app inside facebook, facebook is posting the data to the url you've set in the app settings.

The data you get with that post is the [signed request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) which, unless loaded in a page page, does not include app data.

The sdk you have on the server side (from your code looks like the php sdk) is not aware of the app data, and you need to pass it to the sdk yourself, and because of that you'll have to figure it out yourself.

What I suggest that you would do is to have different canvas urls for the apps, so:

- app #1 gets: example.com/facebookapp1
- app #2 gets: example.com/facebookapp2

You can have the same system to serve those urls, and it will act the same for both except that it will know which app the user asked for.

Comment: But this only returns the page id as far as I know, so I can't get this app running twice on one page, or am I missing out on something?

Comment: What page id? As I wrote, it is up to you do know which app id to use, facebook did not think of everything, or implemented everything, if you want sommething that it not ordinary, you'll have to implement it yourself.

Comment: If I use this link: https://graph.facebook.com/106889492679589, 106889492679589 is the pageid, I always get back this one, not the app id, no matter what URL I use.

Comment: Yes, that's the graph url for the facebook page, not for any app. Why would it return any app id? I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to run the same app twice, in 1 facebook page.
In app1 I want the app to show different data from app2 based on the appID.
It's sort of a CMS that runs from one URL and looks into the database to see which app should run.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Facebook Page ID from the signed request parameter

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Depending on your implementation, you could perhaps use this instead?

Comment: But this only returns the page id as far as I know, so I can't get this app running twice on one page, or am I missing out on something?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to add an app twice on one page have you tried this?

Comment: Yes I have, but I always get the appID of the app that I used to make a connection to Facebook, like this:
$config["appId"]    = 1234;
$config["secret"]   = 4321;
$facebook           = new Facebook($config);

Using signed_request, I always get 1234 from Facebook.

Comment: If you configure the facebook object with a certain app id why would you expect to get a different one later on?

Comment: That's the problem, I actually want to make the facebook connection after I know the appID